# S7.net PLC tag reading exception thrown - Received 12 bytes: '32-02-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-81-04', expected 19 bytes

Tags: siemens

I'm trying to connect to a S7 1212 using this library. I can connect to the PLC fine, but whenever I try and read a tag I get the error exception Received 12 bytes: '32-02-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-81-04', expected 19 bytes.

I'm using the latest version of the software, and as far as I can tell, the PLC is set up correctly.
My code is as basic as it can be:

```
using (var plc = new Plc(CpuType.S71200, "10.10.10.180", 0, 1))
        {
            plc.Open();
            try
            {
                bool tagName = (bool)plc.Read("DB1.DBX0.0");
                Console.WriteLine("Tag Name: " + tagName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

DB1 and OB1:
[image]

Network:
[image]

The permissions are full access and PUT/GET communication is allowed:
[image]

And the Datablock Optimised block access is turned off.

Any idea's why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

The issue was with the PLC itself, not being compiled and downloaded to the CPU (in case this helps anyone else)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, as noted it comes down to the settings being sent to the PLC. You have to write hardware changes to make this work.

[Screenshot of how to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyNkb.png)